# PLSQL Viewing output of sys_refcursor

Tags: plsql, toad

I'm using TOAD for Oracle 11 and am pretty new to SQL.  I have written a proc and am now trying to test and view its output.  I have written the following block:

```
DECLARE
    cur_test SYS_REFCURSOR;

    type t_row is record(psh_code varchar2(20) , pattr_end_date varchar2(20),     pperf_gross varchar2(20));
    r_test t_row;
BEGIN

    procPerfTR(xxx-xxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', :cur_test);
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_test INTO r_test;

        EXIT WHEN cur_test%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur_test;
END;
/
```

However, I get the following error on the LOOP line

ORA-01001: invalid cursor

The error is on line 10 which is the line that has "LOOP" on it

My proc looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procPerfTR

(
    paramPortfCode VARCHAR2, 
    paramEndDate VARCHAR2, 
    paramShare VARCHAR2,
    paramFreq VARCHAR2,

    O_cursorPerf out SYS_REFCURSOR
)

IS

    I_cursorPerf SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

    OPEN I_cursorPerf FOR
    SELECT PS.PSH_CODE, PP.PATTR_END_DATE, PP.PPERF_GROSS
    FROM
        PORTFOLIO_PERFORMANCES PP
        INNER JOIN PORTF_SHARE PS ON PS.PORTF_SHARE_ID = PP.PORTF_SHARE_ID
        INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO P ON P.PORTF_ID = PS.PORTF_ID
        INNER JOIN T_FREQUENCY TF ON TF.FREQUENCY_ID = PP.FREQUENCY_ID
    WHERE
        P.PORTF_CODE = paramPortfCode
        AND PP.PATTR_CALCUL_DATE = PP.PATTR_END_DATE
        AND PP.PATTR_END_DATE = paramEndDate
        AND TF.EXT_CODE = paramFreq
        AND PS.PSH_CODE LIKE
            (CASE 
                WHEN paramShare = 'xxxx' THEN '%xxx'
                WHEN paramShare = 'xxxx' THEN '%xxx'
            END);

    O_cursorPerf:=I_cursorPerf;

END;
/
```

Comment: What is `procPerfTR`?

Comment: It is the proc that I am calling.

Comment: Does this error give you a line number? It might also be helpful if you provide the content of `procPerfTR`, if it's not too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

In your proc invocation, don't put a colon in front of the name of the cursor.  It should look like

```
procPerfTR('xxx-xxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', cur_test);
```

(Note also that I added a single-quote at the start of the first parameter, the absence of which I took to be a simple typo).

Share and enjoy.